# merge indexes of lists in a list if first index value is same in java

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am looking to merge the lists in a list if the 1st index match in Java 8.
I have a list of lists

`[[ABC, 1.0, 4.0, 4.0], [ABC, 2.0, 4.0, 4.0], [ABC, 1.0, 72.0, 72.0], [XYZ, 1.0, 36.0, 36.0], [XYZ, 2.0, 16.0, 16.0]]`

And I want the result as below in an effective way like using stream in java.
Result should be

`[[ABC, 4.0, 116.0, 116.0], [XYZ, 3.0, 52.0, 52.0]]`

Could anyone help please?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question.

Comment: i guess you must write it on your own. Maybe you could use a temporary map to hold the calculated values for every first index.

Comment: By "merge" you mean sum?

Comment: And maybe provide some example code showing what you've tried so far and how your data is organized.

Comment: What are your assumptions on the shape of data? Are inner lists always of length 4, string and 3 numbers? If so, maybe it is better to represent them as a custom data type? If not : can they be longer? Can they be shorter?

Comment: Lesiak: yes the size are same always. I am not a java dev. So looking for a quick sol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case `Collectors.toMap` should be used with the key selected as the first index, and a merge function to sum the rest elements.

Example:

```java
List<List<Object>> input = Arrays.asList(
    Arrays.asList("ABC", 1.0,  4.0,  4.0),
    Arrays.asList("ABC", 2.0, 40.0, 40.0),
    Arrays.asList("ABC", 1.0, 72.0, 72.0),
    Arrays.asList("XYZ", 1.0, 36.0, 36.0),
    Arrays.asList("XYZ", 2.0, 16.0, 16.0)
); 

List<List<Object>> merged = new ArrayList<>(input.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        list -> list.get(0),
        list -> list,
        (l1, l2) -> Stream.concat(
                Stream.of(l1.get(0)),
                IntStream.range(1, l1.size())
                    .mapToObj(i -> (Double)l1.get(i) + (Double)l2.get(i))
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList()),
        LinkedHashMap::new  // keep insertion order
    ))
    .values() // Collection<List<Object>>
);

System.out.println(merged);
// -> [[ABC, 4.0, 116.0, 116.0], [XYZ, 3.0, 52.0, 52.0]]
```

---

However, the input lists seem to be a mix of String and double data and they should be better converted into a class/record with appropriate `merge` function.

Here is the example using `record` available since Java 16 with the `merge` method and overridden `toString` method.

```java
record Item(String name, double ... values) {
    Item merge(Item that) {
        return new Item(
            this.name, 
            IntStream.range(0, this.values.length)
                .mapToDouble(i -> this.values[i] + that.values[i])
                .toArray()
        );
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("[%s, %s]", name, 
            Arrays.stream(values)
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
        );
    }
};

List<Item> data = Arrays.asList(
    new Item("ABC", 1.0,  4.0,  4.0),
    new Item("ABC", 2.0, 40.0, 40.0),
    new Item("ABC", 1.0, 72.0, 72.0),
    new Item("XYZ", 1.0, 36.0, 36.0),
    new Item("XYZ", 2.0, 16.0, 16.0)
); 
List<Item> items = data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toMap(
            Item::name,
            item -> item,
            Item::merge,
            LinkedHashMap::new  // keep insertion order
        ), 
        map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())
    ));

System.out.println(items);
// -> [[ABC, 4.0, 116.0, 116.0], [XYZ, 3.0, 52.0, 52.0]]
```

Comment: error : Syntax error on token ")", ElidedSemicolonAndRightBrace expected at line number 9 and also in l1.size() the l1 is not declared.

Comment: @AshutoshDash, you may check the update

Comment: Thanks Alex, Exactly the solution I was expecting. I have enhanced it lil bit for my problem and it do solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. For each list in the list of lists
2. If first value is not in hashmap add to hashmap using first value as key
3. If key is already in hashmap merge with list already in hashmap
4. Create new list of lists based on hashmap entry set

Extra credit: use LinkedHashMap to preserve order of appearance or TreeMap if you want it in alphabetical order